# Can i capture and send GET requests with wget?

Tags: wget, internet

So, right now i am using Charles to do this and it works fine.

But can i use `wget` to capture and send GET requests? I want to use `wget` and the command line because of the scriptability and customization.

And nope, i have not tried anything yet.

Comment: No, capturing is the realm of a tool like `tcpdump` or `wireshark`. Sending sure.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Wget does not "capture" network packets at all. If you want a look at the response to a GET request, sure.

Answer (score 1):

No, wget is the wrong tool for this sort of thing. However, if you want something like charles that gives you the scriptability and customization of GNU tools, you might want to consider using squid. That's one of the more popular proxies for Linux, and you can customize it pretty heavily.

Comment: Im not on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Sending and responding to HTTP requests are very different tasks. Most software only handles one of the sides: client-side (sending the request and reading the reply) for web browsers and tools like wget, server-side (listening to requests and replying to them) for web servers.

Proxies such as Charles bridge between the two sides. Capturing (i.e. listening to) HTTP requests and transmitting modified requests, and receiving and resending back answers, is the very definition of a proxy. Wget isn't a proxy.

Common scripting languages offer ways to build proxies easily: [HTTP::Proxy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3A%3AProxy) in Perl, [Proxpy](https://code.google.com/p/proxpy/) or [handmade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412581/seriously-simple-python-http-proxy) in Python, [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) in Ruby, etc.